# What makes Scala scalable?

Tags: java, scala

I am a novice learning Scala which is said to be a [scalable Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) . I understand that Scala code compiles into JVM compatible byte code. My questions is what's makes Scala compiler generate a "**scalable bytecode**" and why java compiler i.e. Javac cannot do the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is Scala more scalable than other languages?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130335)

Comment: Have a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151873/scalablity-of-scala-over-java, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130335/why-is-scala-more-scalable-than-other-languages, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130173/how-is-scala-scalable